# Can you use the result of a select statement in the where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this question that I have been struggling with for a couple of hours and can't seem to find a solution to fix it and get the correct answer.

```
select distinct Person.Person.FirstName, Person.Person.LastName, MAX(HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.Rate) - MIN(HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.Rate) AS 'Difference'   
from Person.Person
inner join HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory on HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.BusinessEntityID=Person.BusinessEntityID
where 
group by Person.FirstName, Person.LastName;
```

In the first statement, I use the max and min functions to find the difference between an employee's rate if it had been changed.

The results without using a where statement,

```
Syed    Abbas       0.00,
Kim Abercrombie     0.00,
Hazem   Abolrous    0.00,
Pilar   Ackerman    0.00,
Jay     Adams       0.00,
David   Bradley     13.50,
Alan    Brewer      0.00,
Eric    Brown       0.00,
Jo      Brown       0.00
```

I want to use the result from the max-min in the select statement to only give me the results of the employees who's rate was changed ex: David Bradley 13.50?

Comment: You can use a Having clause instead of a Where clause for aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You don't want to.  What you want is a *having* clause.  This is use for filtering aggregation values:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName,
       (max(eph.Rate) - min(eph.Rate)) as difference   
from Person.Person p join
     HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
     on eph.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
group by p.FirstName, p.LastName
having difference > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7b827e894ac3dcb72a5d0b5b117c4cb) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works for MySQL.

Alternatively, you can use an expression:

```
having max(eph.Rate) > min(eph.Rate)
```

Note other changes to the query:

- Table aliases are used.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.
- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table name, so they are meaningful.
- No `select distinct`.  `select distinct` is almost never appropriate with `group by`, because `group by` already returns distinct rows.
- In MySQL, you can use column aliases in the `having` clause; they cannot be used in the `where`.

Comment: It is giving me an error saying invalid column name 'difference' in the having clause.

Comment: @TyeOuellette . . . It does not generate an error in MySQL.  I have included a sql fiddle.

Comment: If you have sql_mode set to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then I don't think you can use an alias in the Having clause.